# There are too much gap of time between different position of global memory for atomicAdd functions

Tags: cuda, atomic, latency

The main idea of kernel is to get the latency of atomicAdd for global memory, so the first thing is to get the basic latency of atomicAdd for one thread and one block. There are too much gap of time between different position of global memory, why? The kernel is below:
kernel.h

```
#ifndef _KERNEL_H_
#define _KERNEL_H_
template <class T,class ITYPE>
__global__ void collision(T * y,T * oldVal,ITYPE * interval,ITYPE * time)
{

    ITYPE warp,vector_lane,thread_lane,thread_id,partial;
    warp = 32;
    vector_lane = (blockDim.x+warp-1)/warp;
    thread_lane = threadIdx.x & (warp-1);
    thread_id = threadIdx.x / warp;
    ITYPE threads = threadIdx.x;

    ITYPE start_time,end_time;
    ITYPE position = 0;
    T value = 1.0;
    T old = 0.0f;
    partial = threadIdx.x & (warp-1);

    start_time = clock();        

    //set different value for variable position
    old = atomicAdd(&y[position],value);       

    end_time = clock();

    if (thread_lane==0)
        time[blockIdx.x*vector_lane+thread_id]=end_time-start_time;
    oldVal[2]=old;

}

template <class T,class ITYPE>
void __collision__(T * y,T * oldVal,ITYPE * interval,ITYPE * time,ITYPE & number_SM)
{
    const unsigned int THREADS_PER_BLOCK = 1;

    const unsigned int NUM_BLOCKS = 1;

    //get the number of multiprocessors
    ITYPE dev = 0;
    cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, dev);
    number_SM = deviceProp.multiProcessorCount;

    printf("multiProcessors=%d\n",number_SM);

    if (NUM_BLOCKS<13)
        number_SM = NUM_BLOCKS;


    printf("THREADS_PER_BLOCK=%d\n",THREADS_PER_BLOCK);
    printf("NUM_BLOCKS=%d\n",NUM_BLOCKS); 
    collision<T,ITYPE><<<NUM_BLOCKS,THREADS_PER_BLOCK>>>(y,oldVal,interval,time);
}
#endif
```

The code of collision.cu is below:

```
#include "run.h"

using namespace std;

typedef float VALUETYPE;
typedef int INDEXTYPE;

int main(int argc,char *args[])
{
    launtch<VALUETYPE,INDEXTYPE>();
}
```

The code of run.h is below:

```
#ifndef _RUN_H_
#define _RUN_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "kernel.h"
#include <shrQATest.h>
#include <shrUtils.h>
#include <helper_cuda.h>


using namespace std;

template <class T,class ITYPE>
void launtch()
{
    const ITYPE LENGTH = 64*208;
    ITYPE number_SM = 1;
    T * y = new T[LENGTH];
    T * oldVal = new T[LENGTH];
    ITYPE * interval = new ITYPE[LENGTH];
    ITYPE * time = new ITYPE[LENGTH];
    memset(y,0.0f,sizeof(T)*LENGTH);
    memset(oldVal,0.0f,sizeof(T)*LENGTH);
    memset(time,0,sizeof(ITYPE)*LENGTH);
    T * dy;
    T * dOldVal;
    ITYPE * dinterval;
    ITYPE * dtime;

    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&dy,LENGTH*sizeof(T)));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&dOldVal,LENGTH*sizeof(T)));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&dinterval,LENGTH*sizeof(ITYPE)));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&dtime,LENGTH*sizeof(ITYPE)));

    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(dy,y,sizeof(T)*LENGTH,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(dOldVal,oldVal,sizeof(T)*LENGTH,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(dinterval,interval,sizeof(ITYPE)*LENGTH,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    __collision__<T,ITYPE>(dy,dOldVal,dinterval,dtime,number_SM);
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(time,dtime,LENGTH*sizeof(ITYPE),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(y,dy,LENGTH*sizeof(T),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    ITYPE sum=0,count=0;
    for (ITYPE i=0;i<LENGTH;i++)
    {
        if (time[i]>0)
        {
            sum+=time[i];
            count++;
            cout<<" ["<<i<<"]="<<time[i];
        if (count%10==0)
            cout<<endl;

        }

    }
    cout<<endl<<"number_SM="<<number_SM<<endl;
    cout<<"average="<<sum/number_SM<<endl;
    cout<<"y[2]="<<y[2]<<endl;
}

#endif
```

The detail of makefile is below:

```
NVIDIA = /root/NVIDIA_CUDA-5.0_Samples
CUDA = /usr/local/cuda-5.0
#NVIDINCADD = -I$(NVIDIA)/shared/inc -I$(NVIDIA)/C/common/inc
NVIDINCADD = -I$(NVIDIA)/common/inc
CUDAINCADD = -I$(CUDA)/include -I$(CUDA)/shared/inc 
CC = -L/usr/lib64 -lstdc++

GCCOPT = -O2 -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions 
INTELOPT = -O3 -fno-rtti -xW -restrict -fno-alias
#DEB = -g
#NVCC = -G
#ARCH = -arch=sm_13
ARCH = -arch=sm_35

collision:collision.cu
    nvcc $(DEB) $(NVCC) $(ARCH) -lm $(NVIDINCADD) $(CUDAINCADD) -o $(@) $(<) 


clean:
    rm -f collision
    rm -f a.out
```

If the value of position is 0, the value of time[0] is 46; and the postion is 2, the time[0] is 369. The platform is K20M and CUDA 5.0.

Comment: How do you launch your GPU kernel? How do you measure the time?

Comment: The launch GPU kernel is "collision<T,ITYPE><<<NUM_BLOCKS,THREADS_PER_BLOCK>>>(y,oldVal,interval,time);", which is in the "__collision__(...)" of upper code. The measure time is end_time-start_time which is stored in array named time, and start_time is "start_time = clock();" end_time is "end_time = clock();", they are in the upper code either.

Comment: Sorry, T is float, and ITYPE is int.

Comment: Please provide a complete application, not just the kernel code.  is this on linux or windows?

Comment: All the code are provided in the original place,which was modified by me. The order is below:collision.cu->run.h->kernel.h, and makefile is provided either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow that's a huge amount of code mostly unrelated to what you are trying to show.   Next time try and eliminate the unnecessary parts.

Also, you are passing a `float` value as the second parameter to `memset`.  `memset` sets `byte` quantities and expects an `unsigned char` in the second parameter.

With your code, I was able to reproduce some variation between a `position` value of 0 and 2.  For the 0 case I got a time of 76 and for the 2 case I got a time of 118, so not as large as your variation.

However, because you are making the change and then re-compiling the code, the compiler can emit different instruction streams for each case, making the results appear to be different.

I would suggest trying this code instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#define DWIDTH 32
typedef float mytype;

template <typename T>
__global__ void collision(int *time, T *data, T *old ){

  for (int i = 0; i < DWIDTH; i++){
    unsigned long start_time = clock64();
    T my_old = atomicAdd(data+i, (T) 1);
    unsigned long end_time = clock64();
    time[i] = end_time - start_time;
    old[i] = my_old;
    }

}

int main(){
  mytype *h_data, *d_data;
  int *h_time, *d_time;
  mytype *h_old, *d_old;
  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_time, DWIDTH*sizeof(int));
  h_time = (int *)malloc(DWIDTH*sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_data, DWIDTH*sizeof(mytype));
  h_data = (mytype *)malloc(DWIDTH*sizeof(mytype));
  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_old, DWIDTH*sizeof(mytype));
  h_old = (mytype *)malloc(DWIDTH*sizeof(mytype));

  for (int i=0; i<DWIDTH; i++){
    h_time[i] = 0;
    h_data[i] = (mytype) 0;
  }
  cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data, DWIDTH*sizeof(mytype), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_time, h_time, DWIDTH*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  collision<<<1,1>>>(d_time, d_data, d_old);
  cudaMemcpy(h_time, d_time, DWIDTH*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaMemcpy(h_data, d_data, DWIDTH*sizeof(mytype), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaMemcpy(h_old, d_old, DWIDTH*sizeof(mytype), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  std::cout << "times:" << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < DWIDTH; i++)
    std::cout << h_time[i] << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl << "data:" << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < DWIDTH; i++)
    std::cout << h_data[i] << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl << "old:" << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < DWIDTH; i++)
    std::cout << h_old[i] << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile for `sm_35` and run on a K20m, I get:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t284 t284.cu

$ ./t284
times:
98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98 98
data:
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
old:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
$
```

The benefit of this code is that the compiler doesn't have the opportunity to emit a different instruction stream based on whether I set `position` to 0 or 2.  Therefore I get consistent results.

With your code, when I compile with a non-zero value for `position` (and `sm_20`) I get sass like this:

```
    /*0038*/     /*0x40011c042c000001*/     S2R R4, SR_ClockLo;
    /*0040*/     /*0x04411e036000c000*/     SHL.W R4, R4, 0x1;
    /*0048*/     /*0x80015de428004000*/     MOV R5, c [0x0] [0x20];
    /*0050*/     /*0x10519c034801c000*/     IADD R6.CC, R5, 0x4;
    /*0058*/     /*0x00015de218fe0000*/     MOV32I R5, 0x3f800000;
    /*0060*/     /*0x93f1dc4348004000*/     IADD.X R7, RZ, c [0x0] [0x24];
    /*0068*/     /*0x00615e056c7e2800*/     ATOM.E.ADD.F32.FTZ.RN R5, [R6], R5;
    /*0070*/     /*0x40019c042c000001*/     S2R R6, SR_ClockLo;
```

When I compile with a zero value for `position` (and `sm_20`) I get sass like this:

```
    /*0048*/     /*0x40019c042c000001*/     S2R R6, SR_ClockLo;
    /*0050*/     /*0x04619e036000c000*/     SHL.W R6, R6, 0x1;
    /*0058*/     /*0x0001dde218fe0000*/     MOV32I R7, 0x3f800000;
    /*0060*/     /*0x0021de056c7e1000*/     ATOM.E.ADD.F32.FTZ.RN R2, [R2], R7;
    /*0068*/     /*0x4000dc042c000001*/     S2R R3, SR_ClockLo;
```

And so we can see that with your code, the value of `position` may have an impact on the code generated, and therefore the timing.

Comment: The mainly difference between two codes are atomicAdd(data+i, (T) 1),my codes assigned the return value of atomicAdd() to a variation, and Crovella's not. Howere the value of end_time - start_time is the issue atomic operation for there is no return value for atomicAdd(), in other words it does not include the time of atomic operation itself.

Comment: Very well.  I've modified my code in the answer to save away the value of `old`.  The timed portion of the source code is basically identical to yours.  I still get consistent results.  Furthermore, I've shown through the analysis of SASS that your code could not possibly produce consistent results, even if the `atomicAdd` time is consistent.  The compiler is generating a different set of instructions to be timed, in each case.

Comment: I modified Crovella's kernel:template <typename T>
 __global__ void collision(int *time, T *data, T *old ){
 
   //for (int i = 0; i < DWIDTH; i++){
     unsigned long start_time = clock64();
     T my_old = atomicAdd(data+2, (T) 1);
     unsigned long end_time = clock64();
     time[0] = end_time - start_time;
     old[0] = my_old;
   //  } 
  }, I got time[0]=69 for my_old = atomicAdd(data+0, (T) 1), and time[0]=98 for my_old = atomicAdd(data+2, (T) 1), and makefile is -arch=sm_35. So my question is the result is reasonable?

Comment: I've already explained to you why hardcoding the offset (e.g. `data+0` or `data+2` instead of `data+i`) is a mistake, if you want to compare the performance in both cases. Your result is reasonable because the compiler is generating different code in those two cases.